# Spark multinode is not so fast executing a query comparing to single-node, How to increase the number of cores in virtual box?

Tags: apache-spark, virtualbox, cpu, apache-spark-sql

Im doing some tests with spark in virtualbox. I have a cpu with 8 cores in the host machine. And I would like to test spark with maximum cores possible in the virtualbox environment to have the best perforamnce possible.

Im using 3 virtual boxs machines, one master machine, two slaves. I configure in the virtualbox settings the master machine with 2gb RAM and 1CPU, and each salve machine with 4GB RAM and 3CPU.

When I start the spark-shell with yarn the cluster "`spark-shell --mastere yarn-client`" appear with this settings:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTsUF.png)

But Im executing a query, and the same query with just one node without yarn takes 4min, with 3 nodes is taking 2,5min, so its not much difference.

Do you know how can I configure better this enviornment to increase perforamnce?If its possible configure spark with yarn with more cores, given that I have a cpu with 8 cores in the host machine?

I did not any  spark cores configuration to have the values in the above image, the only configs I did in spark were:

(spark-env.sh)

```
SPARK_JAVA_OPTS=-Dspark.driver.port=53411
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/conf
SPARK_MASTER_IP=master
```

(spark-defaults.conf)

```
spark.master            spark://master:7077
spark.serializer        org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
```

(slaves)

```
slave1
slave2
```

And to start spark:

```
spark-shell --master yarn-client
```